# How to eliminate part of a string and save into a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `string` like:

```
/wiki/Bologna_Central_Station
```

I am trying to save it in a `var` like this:

```
countryLinks = doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').attr(href);
```

but I only need to save `Bologna_Central_Station`

Comment: So you only want the string after the last '/' ?

Comment: yes eliminate `/wiki/` basically @Taplar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let pattern = new RegExp('\/wiki\/')

var string = '/wiki/Bologna_Central_Station'

var newString = string.replace(pattern, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do something like `'/wiki/Bologna_Central_Station'.split('/').splice(-1).join()`. This (unlike some of the other solutions) functions with an arbitrary number of slashes (`'/foo/bar/baz/wiki/Bologna_Central_Station'.split('/').splice(-1).join()`)

Example:

```js
var last = '/wiki/Bologna_Central_Station'.split('/').splice(-1).join();
console.log(last);

var last2 = '/foo/bar/baz/wiki/Bologna_Central_Station'.split('/').splice(-1).join();
console.log(last2);
```

Comment: I was thinking about split, but I was thinking more along the lines of then using pop()

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:

`String.replace()` will do it:

```js
var s = "/wiki/Bologna_Central_Station";
console.log(s.replace("/wiki/",""));
```

Or, `String.lastIndexOf()` and `String.substring()` for a more dynamic solution that can handle any amount of `/` characters:

```js
var s = "/wiki/Bologna_Central_Station";

// Find the index position of the last "/" in the string
var lastSlash = s.lastIndexOf("/");

// Extract a substring of the original starting at one more than
// the lastSlash position and going to the end of the string
var result = s.substring(lastSlash + 1);

// Get the part you want:
console.log(result);
```

Or, `String.split()` with `Array.length` to handle any amount of slashes:

```js
var s = "/wiki/Bologna_Central_Station";

// Split on the "/" char and return an array of the parts
var ary = s.split("/");
console.log(ary);

// Get the last elmeent in the array.
// This ensures that it works no matter how many slashes you have
console.log(ary[ary.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can split it based on `/` which gives you an array, from which you can get the required value as

```
var countryLinks = doSelect("Location").siblings('td').find('a').attr(href);
countryLinks=countryLinks.split("/")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var segments = "/wiki/Bologna_Central_Station".split('/');
console.log(segments[segments.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with a simple RegExp and replace for arbitrary amounts of `/`:

```js
var href = "/wiki/Bologna_Central_Station";
var countryLinks = href.replace(/.*\//g,'');
console.log(countryLinks);
```